# Fuseki config.ttl file for inference using the TransitiveReasoner with TDB2

Tags: inference, fuseki, tdb

I am able to run Apache Jena Fuseki 4.6.1 under Windows 10 with no problems when using a config file that includes the following:

```
<#service1> rdf:type fuseki:Service ;
# . . .
  fuseki:dataset <#dataset>
  .

<#dataset> rdf:type ja:DatasetRDFS ;
  ja:dataset <#actualDataset>
  .

<#actualDataset> rdf:type tdb2:DatasetTDB2 ;
  tdb2:location "<path to db folder>"
  .
```

However, I'd like to reduce the reasoning to just the transitive reasoner (`<http://jena.hpl.hp.com/2003/TransitiveReasoner>`), but every example config file I find doesn't work for me. The graph always appears to be empty, as determined by a SPARQL query that counts triples in each named graph.

Does someone have a sample config file with a reasoner configured that actually works?

I've made many attempts using the exact configurations or configurations based on the following:

- https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-configuration.html
- https://apache.googlesource.com/jena/+/streaming-update/jena-fuseki/config-examples.ttl

and others. As mentioned above, with any of these configurations my graph appears to be empty. With the first configuration described above that accepts the default inferencing, everything works as expected, except it's doing more inferencing than I want.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer to my problem as the first answer here:
[Reasoning with Fuseki, TDB and named graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35428064/reasoning-with-fuseki-tdb-and-named-graphs)

This indicates that the apparent emptiness of my graph was eliminated by telling the RDFDataset about each named graph in my database. I do not use the default graph, because default graph behavior varies so much from one triplestore implementation to another. Until I "registered" each named graph in the config file, every query behaved as if the entire triplestore was empty.

At least it's a solution to this problem, which I have been researching unsuccessfully for a long time until now, but it seems quite unsatisfactory that a configuration file needs to be told about named graphs, when named graphs can be created dynamically.